# In pokemon X and Y, what are the starting pokemon's final evolutions?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

In the Pokemon games Pokemon X and Pokemon Y, the starters are Chespin, Fennekin, and Froakie.

What are their final evolutions, their stats and moves and how do they compare? Also, where are they located and how do their base stats compare to legendaries like Arceus and Kyurem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The final evolutions of Chespin, Fennekin, and Froakie are:

Chesnaught: Grass / Fighting

Stats HP: 88, Attack: 107, Defence: 122, S.Attack: 74, S.Deffence: 75, Speed: 64

[image]

Delphox: Fire / psychc

Stats HP: 75, Attack: 69, Defence: 72, S.Attack: 114, S.Deffence: 100, Speed: 104

[image]

Greninja: Water / dark

Stats HP: 72, Attack: 95, Defence: 67, S.Attack:103 , S.Deffence: 71, Speed: 122

[image]

They all evolve at lv 16 then lv 36

For where they are located, they are all located at the second town with all of you friends at the start of the game

Source http://www.serebii.net/xy/pokemon.shtml

Comment: Is this better badp?

Comment: The second evolution is level 36, not 32.

Comment: @qwertyk31 It certainly is getting there.

Comment: @fbueckert fixed

Comment: It may be of interest to note that the three are based on common RPG character archetypes - Chesnaught is a Warrior, Delphox is a Mage, Greninja is a Thief. This has been confirmed as intentional by the developers.

Comment: Hooray the holy trinity!

Comment: Like the trio of legendary Kalos pokemon- the 3 god or justice pokemon are a hawk,deer,and snake, which are Yveltal,Xerneas, and Zygarde respectively.